# Tag suggestion dropdown appears when there are no results sometimes

Tags: bug, design, tag-autocomplete

**Context:** So we all know that, when you're adding tags to a question, a dropdown appears suggesting tags that begin with whatever characters you've typed in so far. When you type in characters that don't match any known tag, the dropdown disappears.

**Bug:** The issue comes if you type in some text that *does* have a matching tag, but you already have that tag on your post. When that happens, you would expect the dropdown to entirely go away. Instead, what happens is that a very short dropdown with no text in it appears.

**Example:** On Stack Overflow, the only tag that starts with "phpsto" is "phpstorm". I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256055/) that was already tagged with "phpstorm", so "phpsto" should have showed no dropdown, but instead it showed the empty dropdown. Here's a screenshot (the dropdown is that rectangle with dark borders just below the tags): [image: screenshot of bug occurring on StackOverflow]

**Environment**: I suspect this bug isn't platform/site-specific, but nonetheless, I'm using Chrome 43 on Fedora 22 64-bit. I have only tested that this bug occurs on Stack Overflow.